# Dragging files into rich textbox resutls icon created

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I read and tried multiple examples in related postings.
No matter what, the problem remains:
When I drag file into the RichBox, I end up with file icon which I don't want and file name string which I do want.

If I drag 2 or more files, only 1st file icon comes, other files do not bring icons.

The question is: how not to get icon into Rich Box when I drag file into it?

```
private void RT1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string s="";
    if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        Array a = (Array)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (string s1 in a)
        {
        RT1.Text = RT1.Text + s1 + "\n";
        this.Activate();
        OpenFile(s1);
        }
    }
}

private void OpenFile(string sFile)
{
    StreamReader StreamReader1 = new StreamReader(sFile);
    RT2.Text = RT2.Text + "\n" + StreamReader1.ReadToEnd();
    StreamReader1.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is technically possible, RichTextBox is one of the last remaining components that still support OLE and allows embedding documents.  What exactly you did to get it to behave like it is still 1999 is impossible to guess from the snippet.

Comment: After adding these two lines to my constructor: `RT1.DragDrop +=RT1_DragDrop; RT1.AllowDrop = true;` If found your other code to work just fine. Not finding these events/properties in the designer's property tab may be a hint that they are not really meant to be used.. No icons just the names and for text files their content..

Comment: Is this in WinForms? Do you have `EnableAutoDragDrop` set to `True` on the RichTextBox?